# Ansible role to Rotate Subnets Availability zone in multiple instance execution for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, subnet

As the title states, I am trying to prevent an instance from selecting the same AZ twice in a row.   My current role is setup to rotate based on available ips.  It works fine but when I run multiple servers, it keeps going to the same AZ.  I need to find a way to prevent it from selecting the same AZ twice in a row.

This is a role that is called during my overall server build

```
#gather vpc and subnet facts to determine where to build the server
- name: gather subnet facts
  ec2_vpc_subnet_facts: 
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
    aws_region: "{{ aws_region }}"
  register: ec2_subnets

- name: initialize build subnets
  set_fact: 
    build_subnet: ""
    free_ips: 0
    previous_subnet_az: ""

- name: pick usable ec2_subnets
  set_fact: 
  # Item.id is sets the current builds subnet Id
    build_subnet: "{{ item.id }}"
    free_ips: "{{ item.available_ip_address_count|int }}"
# Just for debugging and does not work
    previous_subnet_az: " {{ item.availability_zone }}"

  when: ("{{ item.available_ip_address_count|int }}" > free_ips) and ("ansible_subnet" in "{{ item.tags }}") and ("{{ previous_subnet_az|string }}" != "{{ item.availability_zone|string }}")
 # Each subnet in the list 
  with_items: '{{ec2_subnets.subnets}}'
  register: build_subnets


- debug: var=build_subnets var=build_subnet var=previous_subnet_az  
var=selected_subnet
```

Comment: Can you expand more on the reasoning for needing to worry about this? There's a limit on the number of EC2 instances you can spinup in a region, so even if you set this up you'll hit the soft cap well before you'll starve your available IPs (assuming you're just doing EC2 instances)

Comment: Hi @ChrisWhite, the rotation of ips works well (doing count of available ips in each subnet).  The challenge is putting each instance in a different AZ as to not repeat the previously selected one.

Comment: I still want to know what the AZ requirement is about. For example, what requirement do you have that an auto scaling group spanning multiple AZs handling your instance allocation does not meet?

Comment: @ChrisWhite, we are in the early stages of our migration and dont have an ELB set up yet.  The requirement is to provide a High availability infrastructure for our EC2 instances by having multiple AZ.  My original thought was just to use the ALB module but this is not possible currently which is why im working on this work around

Comment: I think you should look into Autoscaling Group, it auto-rebalances instances among multiple AZs. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/auto-scaling-benefits.html#arch-AutoScalingMultiAZ

Comment: We ended up doing a play to validate declare the previous subnet if it was null, then did a conditional to compare then set facts.  This is now answered, thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a play to set the previous subnet when null.  Then did a basic conditional that set the fact of the previous subnet once finishing the first iterations.   Its now solved, thanks everyone.